# How to get a spinner row by knowing the name of the row?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, simpleadapter

I have a simple Android Spinner which I fill with a two column list of "icon" and "name". This works perfect.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> stationList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
... // fill stationList 
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.stations);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                this,
                                stationList,
                                R.layout.listitem,
                                new String[] { "icon", "name" },
                                new int[] {R.id.option_icon, R.id.option_text });
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How can I retrieve a row from the list by just knowing the "name"? I do not know the id nor the position in the spinner!

Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to extend SimpleAdapter and create a `getRowByName(String name)` method and implement it yourself. If you extend SimpleAdapter you will have access to the underlying list so you will have to do some type of iterative search

Comment: There might be an easy way to do what you want... What do you want to do with the row once you have found it?

Comment: @Blundell: Thanks, I can give it a try but it sounds complicated.

Comment: @Sam: I want to make a kind of favorite list and just save the name of the spinner entry. I cannot save the spinner-id because the order of the entries can change form release to release. I need to get the displayed name. Do you have a hint or easy solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search the `stationList` to find a specific value, you can try something like this:

```
for(HashMap<String, Object> map : stationList) {
    if(map.containsValue("name")) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. Thats what I did.